# How do I post data onto a website with Postman?

Tags: json, api, postman, next.js

For my internship I am required to create a database that gathers data from Shopify API and UpKeep API and display information about a customer.

We use Postman to GET data from these sources. However I need some direction when it comes to displaying the data on the localhost. We'll be using Next.JS AND tailwind CSS. Now I know nothing about these in particular.

I am really worried and have begun doing tutorials, but everything is so new to me and I don't want to end up wasting time just researching... Does anyone have any guides online that can give me some guidance for this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman is more the tool for testing in your scenario I believe. Postman can be used to call the APIs to send and receive data.  However, Postman is basically just doing that.  To show the data on a website, you need to do the same calls you are doing with Postman, via the code on the website and display the results.

If you are using Next, then follow there [tutorials](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app).

With the basic application built, you likely then need to follow the [API routes](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/api-routes) to call the external source, retrieve data and display it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really thought Postman was a way to display the data haha